# How do I install Ubuntu when I already have MeeGo pre-installed on a Samsung n100 netbook?

Tags: meego

I have MeeGo pre-installed on my netbook Samsung n100 and hate it. Can anyone give me step by step guide to change over to Ubuntu as I am a complete newbie to this stuff!
thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you sorted this yet?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear you are having troubles with Meego. Is there anything that you can fix on Meego to make it better? Meego is getting less and less support which is another problem but I enjoyed it when I got it working the way I wanted.However I moved on.

If not and you do really want to reinstall it with Meego then it could not be easier.
First of all you need to download Ubuntu from here:
[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)

Then follow the instructions to put it on a pen drive and give it a whirl first booting it from a USB pen drive. If you like it and it works then save any data you need from Meego  (passwords, docs music photos etc) on the pen drive in a new folder and then reboot it and select install and follow the prompts only remembering to select use entire drive or replace current Linux installation.

This will replace your Meego with Ubuntu. Then you can load all your data back on. When installed you may have to sort your settings for a while but I am sure it will work like clockwork.

Let us know how you get on. Enjoy!...and even better let us know what it runs like

Andy

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old entry but in case anyone else is trying..... Ubuntu on the Samsung N100 is no go.

It installs OK and mostly works but there is no driver for the display and the default display drivers incorrectly detect the screen resolution leaving about the bottom third of the screen not accessable.

I posted this on the Ubuntu forum about a month ago but no replies.

I'm really disappointed.

Meego worked but support for it is being dropped in favor of Tizen which is still vaporware.  It also seems to have limited hardware support, specifically I can't make a SmartBro USB modem work with it.

Maybe next year.